# Data binding not giving expected results windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding

In my windows phone app I've implemented data binding which is not yielding me expected results.

My functionality is I've a list box in which I've two textboxes which are data bound.
When I click the textbox datepicker/timepicker will open and the selected value should reflect in the textbox.

The xaml code for the listbox data template is as follows

```
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding TBVisibility}" IsReadOnly="{Binding TBReadOnly}" InputScope="{Binding Numeric}" AcceptsReturn="{Binding MultiLine}" Width="{Binding TBWidth}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=TBText, Mode=TwoWay}" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus_1" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp_1" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus_1" />
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding TB2Visibility}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="140" Text="{Binding TB2Text, Mode=TwoWay}" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus_2" />
```

I'm launching the datepicker and timepicker as follows

```
    private void LaunchDatePicker(TFDetails field)
    {
        datePicker = new CustomDatePicker
        {
            IsTabStop = false,
            MaxHeight = 0,
            Value = field.SelectedDate
        };

        datePicker.DataContext = field;
        datePicker.ValueChanged += DatePicker_ValueChanged;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(datePicker);
        datePicker.ClickDateTemplateButton();
    }
```

Where as "field" is the datacontext of the listbox.

The ValueChanged events are as follows

```
    private void DatePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DatePicker currentDP = sender as DatePicker;
        TFDetails callingField = currentDP.DataContext as TFDetails;
        if (callingField != null)
        {
            callingField.SelectedDate = currentDP.Value;
            callingField.TBText = currentDP.ValueString;
        }
    }
```

When I change the time its not reflecting in the textbox. I wrote INotifyChangedProperty also.

[image] [image]

May I know what mistake I could possible be doing here.

I actually have the same code in a similar UI page where it works perfectly. i don't know what mistake I'm doing here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ListBox is a collection control. If you have a DataTemplate for it, bindings in it will use a single elements of collection boud to ItemsSource as a DataContext rather than DataContext od entire ListBox.

Comment: I'm nt understanding what you are exactly saying. Could you be more clear please ?

Comment: Post the full ListBox code and describe the data structure you bind it to.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. I populated the binding class in onNavigatedTo event. So once the datepicker is closed the OnNavigatedTo event was called so that the fields were populated again. I found a workaround for it.

Comment: Still, post the corresponding code and add an answer with your workaround. For now this question is not beneficial to the community.